# What is this grass and how prevalent is vivipary in grasses?

Tags: grass, germination, lawn

We noticed some seedlings emerging from the flower head of an unidentified grass flower head yesterday. None of us had seen this before and we wondered how common it was and if it is more prevalent under certain conditions. How common is this? Also are these sprouts, which would either drop singularly or attached to the seed head when it drops, as vigorous as seed germinating in or on the soil?

Below are photos for anyone who thinks they might be able to ID.

[image: vivivaporous grass flower]

[image: viviparous grass plant]

[image: grasses]

Comment: What type of answer are you looking for? I don't think I'll be able to find statistics. Also, the 'unidentified grass' isn't helpful. Can you post an identification question and find out what it is?

Comment: Unfortunately we didn't get any photos, but after some research it looks like it might have been poa bulbosa - which usually does this. Should I close this question?

Comment: Don't close the question. Rather, post and accept your own answer, stating what species you think it is, and that this is normal for the species. Posting an example photo  will be beneficial, as well as linking to a database for the species.

Comment: Well?‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: Well i dont think it's Poa bulbosa anymore... So im hoping for someones ID. I did find that some fescues will exhibit vivipary when grown in harsh conditions, but i don't have an "answer" yet.

Comment: Several species of poa produce plantlets instead of seeds on some inflorescence, Poa bulbosa, as noted above, as well as P. alpina. Where were these found (coordinates or nearest inhabited area).

Answer (score 2):

I can't help with the ID but IF mostly you are waiting for a reply to the other of your two inquiries, this will give you an opportunity to close the question.

The structures are stolons.  See a description at [Transplanting and dissecting clump grass](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/21906/transplanting-and-dissecting-clump-grass).  Reproduction by both seed and stolon, as your plants exhibit, is common among grasses. So while that will narrow the suspects slightly, it won't help a lot with identification.